# Why won't neo4j CE 3.0.3 start a second time on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, neo4j

This is incredibly strange to me. Neo4j won't start a second time unless I restart Windows.

I installed neo4j Community Edition 3.0.3 on 64-bit Windows 7 and followed this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Foj2tzq84DY. The tutorial was embedded in neo4j's site https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&flavour=winstall64&release=3.0.3&_ga=1.203356307.385208157.1468345542. Even thought the video lists 2.3 it's linked by Neo4j 3.0.3 download and worked fine for 3.0.3.

Everything worked like a charm. I played around with it for a while and things worked fine. I then shut it down, by clicking on stop in the little gui launcher. When I tried to start it up again, through the start menu, nothing seems to happen at all. I went into the Neo4j CE 3.0.3\bin directory and tried running from there, but I see no error messages, no log directory, no error dialog. I just seems to do nothing. I've also tried "neo4j-ce.exe start" and "neo4j-ce.exe restart". Nothing seems to work.

I checked windows services and didn't see any services starting with neo4j. Don't know if default setup runs it as a service, but if so, maybe it's under something else?

I have been able to get things to start up if I restart Windows, but that's a royal pain and cannot imagine that's intentional.

I do see that there's a jar in the bin directory, so I imagine I could start it with a java command, but I don't know the specifics. However, it's most disconcerting that there is no error message at all. I imagine that something didn't shut down properly, but at this point I have no idea what might be going wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug with the launcher for the community edition of neo4j on windows 7 or not, but what I've found is that when you close the launcher dialog, it does not kill the neo4j-ce process. Thus, since the process is already running, albeit in a stopped state, it won't start again. The challenge there is, of course, that the dialog is gone and you can't click the start button to essentially connect to a database.

The solution is to go into Task Manager and end the "neo4j-ce.exe" process.

Once that is done you can start Neo4j normally.